# How can I configure my .htaccess file such that a query for myurl.com/imageX.bmp where X is some integer all serve up the same image?

Tags: java, .htaccess, variables, image-processing, tracking

I want to be able to take a large number of requests for an image using unique image names (for the purposes of tracking) however I don't want to upload them all. How can I configure my .htaccess file so that all requests for imageX.bmp (image1.bmp image 12.bmp image5438.bmp etc) all return the same image?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy with mod_rewrite:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^path/to/the/images/image([0-9]+)\.bmp$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/the/final/image.bmp
```

This should pretty much do the thing you want, serve the content of the image.bmp to any imageX.bmp request. If you'd like to dwelve deeper into mod_rewrite, [here](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)'s a decent tutorial to get you started.

But, as Goran suggested, appending a parameter to the URI would be simpler, and not much less reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly an answer to your question, but this is what I've come up with (assuming you are using a Unix based OS).

You can do this without `.htaccess` if you create filesystem links for all the filenames.

E.g. you would have one image.bmp, and links image1.bmp, image2.bmp .. ets pointing to image.bmp.

You can create links with:

```
ln -s image.bmp image1.bmp
ln -s image.bmp image2.bmp
```

... etc.

Or with a bash script like this one:

```
 #!/bin/bash
for x in {1..50000}
do
ln -s image.bmp image$x.bmp
done
```

This way, you would have just one file served to all requests.

But, there may be an even better way to solve your problem!

Simply add a GET parameter to your request like this:

http://domain.foo.com/path/image.bmp?number=12334

Then, have a web app marking all requests and their numbers. Or have all requests logged in apache log and parse it out later.

Hope any of these actually help!

Answer (score 0):

+1 for using image.bmp?number=12345 instead of image12345.bmp